# Why is builder not finding JSON?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to deploy my kivy app to Android. The problem is that every time I run `buildozer android debug deploy run logcat` I get this

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement json
ERROR: No matching distribution found for json
```

Here is the link to the output of Buildozer: https://pastebin.pl/view/63f40402

The problem from what ive seen is around line 630 in the pastebin.
I can see that Buildozer is making a request to `https://pypi.org/simple/json/` to get something but the response code is 404...

Can anyone have a look cuz I am really stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to add `json` in your requirements. As `json` is a built-in module, it will automatically get added when you add `python`. So, just remove `json` from the requirements of your `buildozer.spec` file and then run buildozer